# Lusin spaces: Issues on the definition, and on spaces used in analysis that are not Lusin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I have two questions concerning Lusin spaces. Before the questions, the definition:

> **Definition (Lusin Space):** Given a Hausdorff space $(X, \tau)$, that space is said to be *Lusin* if there is a stronger topology $\tau’$ on $X$ such that $(X , \tau’)$ is Polish.

Below there are my questions, where – in italics – there are my thoughts over them.

**Questions:**

1. Has the topology $\tau’$ to be **strictly** stronger than $\tau$?
   *[I would say not. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the euclidean topology is Hausdorff, and it is polish, thus with that topology it is already Lusin, right?]*
2. In the book, I found that most of the spaces encountered in analysis are Lusin. What are those spaces that are **not** Lusin?
   *[I can think of a space that is not Lusin, but I don’t think it is a workhorse in analysis… Take a uncountably infinite space $(X, \tau_d)$ endowed with the discrete topology: then it is metrizable, and complete, but not separable, because it is not second countable, hence not polish, and from point 1, not Lusin, right?]*

As always, any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey which textbook does this definition of Lusin space come from?

Comment: @EvanKim: sorry for the terribly late answer. The book is Laurent Schwartz's "Radon Measures on Arbitrary Topological Spaces and Cylindrical Measures".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, it doesn't have to be strictly stronger.  Polish spaces are Lusin.
2. Most spaces encountered in analysis are Polish.  You are right that an uncountable discrete space is a counterexample (but be a little careful: "not Polish" does not imply "not Lusin".  The key here is that there are no other topologies stronger than the discrete topology.)  Any other non-separable metric space works too; $\ell^\infty$ is another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! **+1** for the point you make it is false that "not Polish implies not Lusin". (Actually, the first thing I thought was that we cannot find a topology stronger than the discrete one, but still in phrasing I got caught on the fly in the fallacy of the converse).

Comment: I meant the fallacy of denying the antecedent... :)

Comment: May I ask you one last thing I was thinking about? What is a common space in analysis that is Lusin, but it is not Polish?

Comment: @Kolmin: The first example that comes to my mind is the weak topology on a separable Banach space.

Comment: Thus, just to be sure I understood, you say that given an arbitrary Banach space $X$ that it is also separable (which makes it overall Polish), if we endow it with the weak topology, then it is Lusin, but not Polish anymore. Now, If I got it right, concerning $\Delta (X)$ (the set of all Borel probability measures over our original $X$), this is still Polish even with the weak*-topology (the topology of weak convergence). Now, again, if this is right, I am just wondering if there is a way to make it Lusin but not Polish. (I hope I didn't write lot of nonsense). :)

Comment: @Kolmin: Well, by very definition, any weaker Hausdorff topology on $\Delta(X)$ would accomplish that, but I can't think of any that are commonly used in analysis.  Maybe you should sort through what you really want to know and ask a new question.  Right now it seems like we are just trying to randomly form connections between things with no clear goal.

Comment: Yeah, you are completely right. Indeed, I didn't really have a full developed question. Rather, I had a thought and: (a) I wanted to check if the statement (the thought itself) made sense, and (b) well, I was looking for the answer as well. Thanks a lot! I will post a question as soon as I have a full developed idea.